# ASP MVC3 - Make second call to controller once jQuery autocomplete value selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

Below are the jQuery versions that I am referencing in my ASP MVC view

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Using the `autocomplete` widget, I would like the form to fill out a separate text box based on the user's selection from the `autocomplete` list. On this page, the user will begin typing a bank name. Once the user selects which bank they need, another field by the name of `Dynamics ID` needs to be populated with the appropriate value. Here is the jQuery as it's written right now

```
$(function () {
    $("#BankNameAuto").autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("GetBanks", "AgentTransmission")',
        minLength: 1,
        onComplete: function (data) {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetDynamicsId", "AgentTransmission")', data, function (result) {
                $('Dynamics').val(result);
            })
        }
    });
});
```

And here are the two controller methods that are called in the above jQuery

```
    //GET
    public JsonResult GetBanks(string term)
    {
        var banks = from c in db.BankListMaster.Where(n => n.BankName.Contains(term))
                        select c.BankName;

        banks = banks.Distinct();

        return Json(banks, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    //GET
    public JsonResult GetDynamicsId(string term)
    {
        var dynamics = from c in db.BankListMaster.Where(n => n.BankName.Equals(term))
                    select c.LinkRepsToDynamicsUniqueId;

        dynamics = dynamics.Distinct();

        return Json(dynamics, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

<strike>Once the user has made a selection from the list, I wanted to be able to send back the `ID` value to that bank. That serves as the primary key for the `BankListMaster` table, of which `BankName` and `DynamicsId` are both fields. I'm still new to jQuery, however, so I may not be able to do this.</strike>

Right now, I've set a breakpoint in the first line of both controller methods. The `GetBanks` breakpoint fires everytime, however I cannot get the `GetDynamicsId` to fire at all.

EDIT

Since I'm only selecting the `BankName` field in the first query, I adjusted the `GetDynamicsId` method to use the bank name as the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something similar by handling the "select" event.  It's not "onComplete" as you had in your example.  Your code with this change would be:

```
$(function () {
    $("#BankNameAuto").autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("GetBanks", "AgentTransmission")',
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetDynamicsId", "AgentTransmission")', { term: ui.item.value }, function (result) {
                $('Dynamics').val(result);
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Odd... after implementing this code, I can no longer select an item from the `autocomplete` drop down list. The list shows up correctly, and adjusts as I continue to type as well, however if I click on a name nothing happens. The breakpoint in the `GetDynamicsId` doesn't fire as well. Unfortunately I don't see any errors in the Chrome debugger either.

Comment: Actually, I take that second part back. In the console, once I click on a name from the `autocomplete` list I get an `UncaughtTypeError: Illegal Invocation` message. The jQuery that is referenced in this error is `jquery-1.8.3.js`

Comment: Changing the `select` method signature to the following is allowing the breakpoint in the `GetDynamicsId` to fire (might want to adjust the code in your answer): `select: function (event, ui)`

Comment: also, change the `$.getJSON` method signature to the following as well so I can accept it as an answer: `$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetDynamicsId", "AgentTransmission")', { term: ui.item.value }, function (result)`